# JSONata grouping in new objects

Tags: json, grouping, jsonata

I'm looking for a solution of grouping elements from a flat hierarchy into a encapsulated one with the help of JSONata.

Given that I have the following input data:

```
[  
  {
    "restaurantName": "Pizza Place",
    "restaurantId": "1",
    "dishName": "Margherita  Pizza",
    "dishId": "A"
  },
  {
    "restaurantName": "Pizza Place",
    "restaurantId": "1",
    "dishName": "Four Cheese Pizza",
    "dishId": "B"
  },
  {
    "restaurantName": "Pizza Palace",
    "restaurantId": "2",
    "dishName": "Margherita  Pizza",
    "dishId": "A"
  },
  {
    "restaurantName": "Pizza Palace",
    "restaurantId": "2",
    "dishName": "Four Cheese Pizza",
    "dishId": "B"
  },
  {
    "restaurantName": "Pizza Palace",
    "restaurantId": "2",
    "dishName": "Pepperoni Pizza",
    "dishId": "C"
  }
]
```

I want to group them together by restaurants like so:

```
[
  {
    "restaurantName": "Pizza Place",
    "restaurantId": "1",
    "menu": [
      {
        "dishName": "Margherita  Pizza",
        "dishId": "A"
      },
      {
        "dishName": "Four Cheese Pizza",
        "dishId": "B"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "restaurantName": "Pizza Palace",
    "restaurantId": "2",
    "menu": [
      {
        "dishName": "Margherita  Pizza",
        "dishId": "A"
      },
      {
        "dishName": "Four Cheese Pizza",
        "dishId": "B"
      },
      {
        "dishName": "Pepperoni Pizza",
        "dishId": "C"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I already tried to find a solution with the help of the JSONata Exerciser and this solution seems to work on the reduced input data set but as soon as I use the full data set (just more restaurants and more dishes) I can a time out exception (maybe due to infinite loops):

```
$distinct(
        $map($distinct($), function($v0, $i, $a) {
        {
            "restaurantName":$v0.restaurantName,
            "restaurantId": $v0.restaurantId,
            "menu":$distinct($filter($$, function($v1,$i,$a) {$v1.restaurantId = $v0.restaurantId}).{
                "dishName": dishName,
                "dishId": dishId
            })
        }
    })
)
```

If anyone has a solution and an explanation on how to best achieve this with JSONata this would be of great help.

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `restaurantId` into an object, and then iterate over object entries using the [$each function](https://docs.jsonata.org/object-functions#each):

```
$${
  restaurantId: $
} ~> $each(function($objects, $id) {{
  "restaurantId": $id,
  "restaurantName": $objects[0].restaurantName,
  "menu": $objects.{
    "dishName": dishName,
    "dishId": dishId
  }
}})
```

Check it out on the Stedi Playground: https://stedi.link/qJhXW0h

Comment: Thanks, I will need to spend some time with the documentation to understand what is going on. :)

Comment: I'm pretty good with jsonata and I don't understand whats going on:

$$ is the root of the graph
$${ } is the reduce function, so the output.
$${restaurantId: ...}  means we want the output to include the "restaurantId" field
$${restaurantId:$} how is it possible that this groups by restaurant id ????

Can you elaborate? thank you.

Comment: ahh got it!
$$ is the root graph
$${...} is the GROUPING function
$${restaurantId:...} is group by restaurant id
$${restaurantId: $} is group everything by restaurant id!
 thank you.

Comment: Yeah, the grouping operator is quite useful for that kind of processing: https://docs.jsonata.org/sorting-grouping#grouping

And it's much less verbose than a $reduce function which you can use here too of course.

Comment: If we had to use the `$reduce` function the solution would look something like this: https://stedi.link/26MYy83

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work and I feel is a little more intuitive to follow:

```
${
    (restaurantName & restaurantId): {
        "restaurantName": $[0].restaurantName,
        "restaurantId": $[0].restaurantId,
        "menu": $.$sift(function($_, $k){$k~>/^dish/})
    }
}.*
```

Grouping by `restaurantName` and `restaurantId`, we map the name and id for each group and pick out the `dish*` properties to build out the `menu`. Then map to the values of the grouping.